# How to share my newly developed utility software?

Tags: java, itunes, m3u

I just finished developing an utility standalone application, and would like to share for free with the largest possible people. Just for them to benefit of what I've done... and get ideas on how to improve that software.

1. What are the channels I should use ?
2. As I would love to have feedback about how to improve the software itself, I want to have a way collect and answer these... Is making a new Gmail address the best way ?

In order for the answers to be more contextualized :

i. Here is what this application is about :

- Getting M3U playlists from iTunes.
- Exporting the specifically concerned mp3 files as well in a new folder organized nicely.

ii. The code is not what I want to share, just the "executable".

iii. It is written in pure JAVA, but the executable is encapsulated for Windows.

Comment: The standard place for sharing software these days is github.  However, this is for sharing **source code**.  The flipside is that people who have a clue about security won't touch your application unless they can audit the source code to make sure that it isn't malware.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Anybody else thinks I should close this question ? I don't want to have an out of scope question... But on another hand, one of the possible last step of software development is to share it no ?

Comment: *"But on another hand, one of the possible last step of software development is to share it no ?"* - Possibly.  (A lot of people would disagree with that!)  But either way, the "sharing" step is not programming.  It is marketing, or market research, or something like that.

Comment: Hello Stephen, I am fairly new to Stackoverflow, and honestly don't know where else post this question... But as you have had a vote as well, I close this question as asked. Have a nice day !

Comment: You could post it on a discussion board; e.g. Quora.

Comment: Nicely suggested... Thank you... This closes the discussion... (except I think it's a moderator who has to close the question, no?)

Comment: You can delete your own questions ... so long as they have no answers.

Comment: But leaving it will prevent others who have the same question to do same as I did... I'll just let it as is... And will ask a moderator to take care of that... whenever possible... Thanks again, I'll post (research first) on Quora !